# BizTalk: Catch exception in orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I'm new in BizTalk, I want to add catch exception in orchestration, but I do not see any component like `CatchException` in Toolbox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding a Scope component, then create new Exception Handler in Scope component.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Thien Long, your answer is help.